# How to override default jar present inside jre/lib folder

Tags: java, jar, lib

open jdk Charset.jar is present inside my jre/lib folder... But i want to use ibm's charset.jar instead because it has support for more character set.

Replacing  the file directly from lib directory is  working fine for me.
Do we have any alternative method which can override default jars inside jre lib

IDE: eclipse
JDK: 1.8

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a replacement file to the beginning of the boot classpath using the following VM option (example is for Windows):

```
-Xbootclasspath/p:C:\path\to\other\charset.jar
```

E.g. if you packaged you code in a `myapp.jar` file, and have renamed the IBM version to `ibm_charset.jar` and have both files in the current directory, you'd run:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:ibm_charset.jar -jar myapp.jar
```

Comment: Tried the first option and is working fine now... Thanks @Andreas